# Static assert for companion object being passed as AnyRef

Tags: scala, static-assert

For akka-like frameworks it's pretty common situation with typos when companion object is sent or matched(expected) instead of case class instance and vice versa.
With code like:

```
case class Foo()
...
def receive(ev: AnyRef) = {
...
    case Foo() =>
        // do some stuff
...
}
```

ocassionally sending like this:

```
actor ! Foo
```

instead of

```
actor ! Foo()
```

Erroneous version compiles perfectly but code doesn't work like it's expected to (for obvious reasons).

**Now the question**: is there any way to specify some static (compile time) assertion that companion objects (maybe with exception of "case object Foo") could not be passed to ! operator? And also for receive-like functions some way to specify that it should not contain matching cases for them.

or

Some way to prevent parameterless case classes from being declared (to force case objects for these cases). E. g. compiler option that will make 'case class Foo()' illegal to force usage of 'case object Foo'. But that's will not prevent from case Foo => from being used instead of case Foo(_) => for case classes with parameters (use case: actor could just redirect some of received messages ignoring parameters).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar thought a few weeks back, here are the things I concluded:

I can't really force Akka to only consider taking a certain type of data without overriding a good chunk of the framework or implementing my own checks at receive and at send. For instance, you could wrap your send operations in methods you call that only accept a certain type of parameters.

If I understand correctly your second question, you would like the following `val a = Foo` to be prohibited, that's not really possible since it's fine by Scala to have a value hold a type.

Between creating my own implementation of the framework and wrapping my send calls, I opted for methods that wrap my send and ask calls that, as I said, only accept a certain type of parameters. It worked well. Something like:

```
def customSend[T <: MyType](msg: T) = 
  actor ! msg
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Clarification on second question: compiler option that will make declaration 'case class Foo()' illegal to force 'case object Foo'. But it will not prevent all related errors as your actor could be not interested in message parameters and just wants to redirect it somewhere so you still could write case x : Foo ocasionally even if Foo is declared with parameters case class Foo(a: Int).

Comment: I see, I, however, have no idea how to achieve that... I would very interested to know if it's possible.

Comment: By the way, you can also name `customSend`: `!` instead. This way you could still seamlessly use the `actor ! msg` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The usual (or unusual) way to exclude a type from getting inferred is by the ambiguous implicits trick.

But since scalac will not infer a singleton type, you can't get it to fall for the trick.

A lesser alternative would be to overload the polymorphic method, such that one method receives the singleton and the other one doesn't.

Then you could at least catch the programming error on the sender side.

```
scala> object F {
     | def f[A](a: A) = println(a)
     | def f[A <: Singleton](a: A)(implicit d: DummyImplicit) = println(s"Reject $a")
     | }
defined object F

scala> F f 3
3

scala> object X
defined object X

scala> F f X
Reject $line5.$read$$iw$$iw$X$@5aa9e4eb

scala> F f (3: Singleton)
Reject 3

scala> F f[Singleton] 3
<console>:9: error: overloaded method value f with alternatives:
  (a: Singleton)(implicit d: DummyImplicit)Unit <and>
  (a: Singleton)Unit
 cannot be applied to (Int)
              F f[Singleton] 3
              ^
```

This is not helpful:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

  trait NoSing[A]
  implicit val `no sing 1`: NoSing[Singleton] = null.asInstanceOf[NoSing[Singleton]]
  implicit val `no sing 2`: NoSing[Singleton] = null.asInstanceOf[NoSing[Singleton]]
  implicit def `anything but`[A]: NoSing[A]   = null.asInstanceOf[NoSing[A]]

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait NoSing
no sing 1: NoSing[Singleton] = null
no sing 2: NoSing[Singleton] = null
anything$u0020but: [A]=> NoSing[A]

scala> object G {
     | def g[A : NoSing](a: A) = println(a)
     | }
defined object G

scala> G g X
$line5.$read$$iw$$iw$X$@5aa9e4eb

scala> G g[Singleton] X
<console>:14: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both value no sing 1 of type => NoSing[Singleton]
 and value no sing 2 of type => NoSing[Singleton]
 match expected type NoSing[Singleton]
              G g[Singleton] X
                ^
```

Comment: Thanks. Solution looks pretty complex but maybe I will try that. Can you give me some link to documentation on Singleton class? It's not that easy to find due to the name. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html says nothing about it even though I have autocompletion for it in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Overloading your custom send method is pretty simple, but not perfect. http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#singleton-types and http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#conformance